# Condition Inside String in Bashscript

Tags: bash, shell-script, string, prompt

I want to print exit code of previous command in shell if it failed. So I changed `PS1` variable in `/etc/bash.bashrc` like this:

```
PS1='${debian_chroot:+($debian_chroot)}\u@\h:\w [$?] \$ '
#_______________________________________________^^^^_____
```

but it always print the exit code of the previous command. Is there any way to add condition in the template so if `$?` is equal to `0`, it does not print `$?`

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You can create conditions and expressions inside `$()` like this:

```
echo "$( var=2; echo $var)"
```

in your example you can change `PS1` variable like this:

```
PS1='${debian_chroot:+($debian_chroot)}\u@\h:\w $(
    status=$?; (( status != 0 )) && echo "[$status] "
)\$ '
```

looks like:

```
jackman@b7q9bw1:~ $ echo hello
hello
jackman@b7q9bw1:~ $ sh -c 'exit 42'
jackman@b7q9bw1:~ [42] $
```

Answer (score 0):

Bash executes the code in the variable [`PROMPT_COMMAND`](https://www.gnu.org/software/bash/manual/bash.html#Controlling-the-Prompt) before printing the prompt. One of the things you can do that is to calculate components of the prompt which are then assembled via the `PS1` setting.

```
PROMPT_COMMAND_set_status () {
  if ((last_status == 0)); then
    PS1_status=
  else
    PS1_status="[$last_status] "
  fi
}
PS1=PS1='${debian_chroot:+($debian_chroot)}\u@\h:\w $PS1_status\$ '
PROMPT_COMMAND='last_status=$?; PROMPT_COMMAND_set_status'
```